# Unity Game wont play sounds when exported to the web?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, webgl

I've heard it used to be a bug that got fixed on 2021, but I'm not sure if its back or if it's an issue with my project. I'm trying to play music and sound effects at certain parts of my game, but it simply has 0 audio(and yes, I've checked the tab isn't muted)

when I open the browser's console, it throws this error:
[image]
And when I switch from any system in the build settings to WEB within unity, I get these:

[image]

The audios work fine on Windows, Linux and Android. I've tried only adding an iframe to my game once the user clicks a button on the page, thinking it could be the old issue where the browser blocks autoplays until the user click the page but it also didn't fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are seeing that AudioContext message then it's the autoplay problem. Is the build on the same domain? Maybe it's because of the way you add the iframe after click. I'd also suggest you try to put the unity build directly on your page, instead of using the iframe. I haven't done it in a while, but it should be as simple as copying the html.

Comment: @zoran404 can't upload the game to my page for size reasons, but even when loading on the iframe's domain it won't work(same errors)